# TYPO3 tx_form copy to sender (recipient copy)

Tags: php, forms, typo3

I've been searching the internet for hours, checked the TYPO3 documentation, TS reference and so on, but didn't find any hint how to get the TYPO3 6.2 standard form to send a copy to the initial sender of the form.

Maybe it just isn't possible because of the danger of someone sending SPAM to any email addres using this form? I think in combination with a good SPAM filter this should be a manageable thread, and besides, every submitted form will also be sent to the website owner who can intervenate and shut down the form if anything bad happens.

In the old versions of TYPO3 in the standard form it was possible:

```
| recipient_copy=hidden | copy@email.com
```

So, I look for something like this:

```
enctype = multipart/form-data
method = post
prefix = tx_form
confirmation = 
postProcessor {
    1 = mail
    1 {
        recipientEmail = receipient@mail.com
        recipientEmailCopyField = field_from_mailform //doesn't exist, but im looking for something like this
        senderEmail = webmaster@website.com
        subject = Lorem Ipsum
        messages {
            success = TEXT
            success {
                value = <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No solution so far, I work with Powermail now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not a direct answer to your Question, but I recomment to not use the system extension form, but a more established extension like e.g. powermail2 or formhandler.

**UPDATE:**

While the former was my recommendation for TYPO3 6.2 I would gladly point to the comment below from Björn:

> With TYPO3 7 LTS the system extension "form" received a major improvement. Most parts of the extension were rewriten and are now based on extbase and fluid. The mail postProcessor is now complettely stdWrap-able and you can do something as proposed over here: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/32950#note-15. In TYPO3 8 the development of form will continue.

So for most task the sysext form should now be suitable.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree, 24 hours and no answer, I think, nobody cares, because there are two good other extensions for it, so everybody simply choses the work around. I'm just not so fond of extensions, always giving some extra risk to the security of your website. I just remember the critical security issue of powermail some years ago...

Comment: I do not agree on using powermail2 or formhandler. You have to install  sysext "Form". This standard form extension is even multi page enebled. Otherwise If you do not install the sysext "Form" you have a very simple standard "Form" content in TYPO3 6.2, and this version, indeed, is to basic.

Comment: With TYPO3 7 LTS the system extension "form" received a major improvement. Most parts of the extension were rewriten and are now based on extbase and fluid. The mail postProcessor is now complettely stdWrap-able and you can do something as proposed over here: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/32950#note-15. In TYPO3 8 the development of form will continue. Stay tuned, it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I made a extension to fix this, I just added an ccEmailField to the MailPostProcessor of form. Install the extension and use it. More info on the REAME on github:

https://github.com/taywa/t3ext-taywa_ccemailfield

or:
https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/taywa_ccemailfield

just use it like this:

```
method = post
prefix = tx_form
confirmation = 0
postProcessor {
    1 = mail
    1 {
        ccEmailField = email # uses field named "email"
        recipientEmail = noise@taywa.ch
        senderEmail = noise@taywa.ch
        subject = Test of ccEmailField
        messages {
            success = TEXT
            success {
                value = <p>See you</p>
            }
        }
    }
}
10 {
    type = email
    name = email
    placeholder = Email
    required = required
    label {
        value = Email
    }
}
20 = SUBMIT
20 {
    type = submit
    name = submit
    value = Submit
}
```

Comment: The "form" extension coming with TYPO3 8 LTS does allow this out of the box. You just provide the fieldname and it will make an cc

Answer (score 0):

In typo3_8 and later there is options: `carbonCopyAddress` and `blindCarbonCopyAddress` so problem is easy to solve in new version and any other extensions are no needed.

Answer (score -1):

just a suggestion - not testet. But maybe this can be done by defining a second post processor like this?:

```html
2 = mail
2 {
  recipientEmail = tx_form[21]
  senderEmail = webmaster@website.com
  subject = Lorem Ipsum
  messages {
    success = TEXT
    success {
      value = <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    }
  }
}
```

With king regards

Comment: ähm, there are more postprocessor options - have a look for "recipientEmailField" or "replyToField" or "senderEmailField"

Comment: here i found more info: 

http://alumnitypo3.blogspot.de/2012/01/form-einfaches-nachrichtensystem-fur.html 

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/32950